# Eclipse: Google play services lib doesn't exist in Rev. 30+

Tags: eclipse, jar, google-play-services

I know, that's using Eclipse for Android app development is a bad idea, but I've some issues why I can't use Android Studio

So after updating SDK to android N and google play services to rev.31 google play lib doesn't exist.

I've already googled that it goes on another folder as .ass files, but I don't know how to transfer it usual .jar

Any ideas instead of using Android Studio and continue with Eclipse in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Google separated google-play-services to smaller parts because of high weight

You'll find them(take in mind that services are separated) in /extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms

1. Find library, which you need (ads for example)
2. Rename .aar to .zip
3. Unzip the file
4. Import the project into Eclipse by using New -> Project -> Android Project from Existing Source Code
5. Go to the Project's properties and set the Build Target and 'Is Library' flag
6. Go into your project properties and link library, which you created

PS 0-4 can be replaced by downloading libs here: 
https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-base